# How to switch from the code/script to the terminal in vscode without mouse usage

Tags: visual-studio-code

I dont want to use my mouse to move to the terminal below the script in VSCode.
Example:
I have a python terminal below, which I would like to experiment in between writing the script.

Comment: Is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1270103/how-to-switch-the-cursor-between-terminal-and-code-in-vscode) answer your question ?

Comment: use  ctrl  + ` to open a terminal  and use ctrl  +shift + ` to  open a new terminal. [vs code cheat sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJjdO_j_byAhUqgUsFHTLDA7wQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.visualstudio.com%2Fshortcuts%2Fkeyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3IhUv6JwiLHEL2SrhdVrIp)